# referencing and closing thread instantly

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public class GUI 
{
    public void threadTask()
    {
        while(MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE)
        {
            // do something
        }             
    }
}

// Execute Thread
GUI gui = new GUI();
Thread t = new Thread(threadTask);
t.Start();
```

This seems like a messy way to do this. Any better approach how to reference it and kill it instantly? Thanks!

UPDATE: who ever gave me a downvote, LEARN TO READ! I clearly specified what I'm trying to 'kill' in the title, tags and code, at least next time read the post before casting a vote.

Comment: What do you mean by "kill it"? Kill what?

Comment: your question is not clear.  what do you mean by "reference it and kill it instantly"?

Comment: the 'Thread' obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't kill/dispose a thread, it has no IDisposable.

You could put the thread start in a method, so you can call it more then once, when it finished the first time.

You can use:

```
t.Join();
```

to catch when the thread finished.

The call to Join() is what de-allocates the thread. You don't have to do anything else. Just make sure that the threads clean up any resources they might be using before they exit.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine, the thread will be cleaned up as soon as it's finished processing.